# Which ubuntu to choose

Tags: system-installation

I am switching from windows 8.1 to ubuntu which ubunutu you prefer me to choose? Laptop info(intel i7 3rd ino, 8gbRAM radeon graphics, samsung)

Comment: "minimal requirements"? with those specs? unlikely :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you have a powerfull laptop.

It's recommended to install **Ubuntu 14.04 lts 64bit**.

Download it by going to [Ubuntu's Official Site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)

Comment: today i saw 14.10 version of ubuntu now im between 14.10 and 14.04 i dont know which to install...please your recommends...

Comment: It's better to install 14.04 than 14.10.
14.04 is a stable release.Also it is an lts release.
On the other hand, 14.10 is in development (Beta) yet.